# DB::transaction(function () use ($request) not working in laravel controller

Tags: database, laravel

Whenever trigger this method, not executing the code inside `DB::transaction(function () use ($request)`

This is full code is here

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {

    $password = $request->password;
    $tb = $this->userService->storeStudent($request);

    try {
        // Fire event to store Student information
        if(event(new StudentInfoUpdateRequested($request,$tb->id))){

            // Fire event to send welcome email
            event(new UserRegistered($tb, $password));
        } else {

            throw new \Exeception('Event returned false');
        }
    } catch(\Exception $ex) {

        Log::info('Email failed to send to this address: '.$tb->email.'\n'.$ex->getMessage());
    }
});
```

I am using PostgreSQL. Help me to solve this problem

Comment: How do you know that is is not executed?

Comment: Return request from the inside transaction method

Comment: You need to return `DB::transaction(...` as well as returning inside the closure: `return DB::transaction(...`

Comment: Return nothing when return DB::trasaction